# Redirecting script to index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I don't really know what is going wrong. I have my logout page which I redirected to the login folder:

```
<?php

//include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions.php';

if(session_destroy()){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user_name'])){
setcookie("user_name", $user_name, time()-2592000); 
    }
}
    header('location:'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/login/');
?>
```

But it always redirects me back to my index page even when I try to run the code like this:

```
<?php

//include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connect.php';
//include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/functions.php';

session_start();

if(session_destroy()){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user_name'])){
setcookie("user_name", $user_name, time()-2592000); 
    }
}
?>
```

Without including any external page and no header location it still redirects me back to the index page and secondly it doesn't destroy the session after redirecting to the index page until I reload it. Please do any one know the possible cause?

Comment: You should provide your .htaccess code here too

Comment: I am using WAMP local sever and even when I remove the inclusion it still does same thing.

Comment: Provide your .htaccess code. We cannot help you without it.

Comment: `header('location:'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/login/')` - that makes no sense whatsoever. Step 1: Stop confusing file system paths with URLs.

Comment: Bad to say, I didn't create any .htaccess code

Comment: @CBroe... Please which is the best way to go to my root folder from any where because I don't want to edit my code when I want to upload it to the server, its a lot of stress

Comment: Open your developer console. Go to the network tab. Tell us what **really** happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives the directory root of the file. For
>   inclusion or redirect `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` along with `http://`
>   or `https://` is necessary to use.

```
   <?php

    $base_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];


    include $base_url.'/functions.php';

    if(session_destroy()){
        if(isset($_COOKIE['user_name'])){
    setcookie("user_name", $user_name, time()-2592000); 
        }
    }
        header('location:'. $base_url .'/login/');
    ?>
```